# Echo outputting to console instead of HTML

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

My problem is that the values are successfully inserted into my DB, but my echo of 'success' doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
$conn =  new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$cpw = $_POST['cpw'];

if($pw !== $cpw) {
die("Passwords do not match");
}


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO snpdata (Username, Password, Email, 
Gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

if(!$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $sname, $clean_pw, $clean_em, $gen)) {
    die("Error binding parameters");
} else {}

$gen = $_POST['gender'];
$sname = $_POST['sname'];
$em = $_POST['em'];

$clean_pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$clean_em = password_hash($em, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die ('Error executing' . $stmt->error);
} else { 
    echo '<h3 color="green"> SUCCESS </h3>';
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I've tried researching how to echo html, but it yielded the same results as what I put in this code.

EDIT: Sorry for not being clear, the problem is that the echo doesn't show up on the page at all.

Here is the AJAX, it works fine.

```
<script>
function formSubmit() {
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: 'snp.php',
data: $('#fm').serialize(),
success:function(response) {
$('#success').html(response);
}

});
var form = document.getElementById('fm').reset()
return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is my form code:

```
<form id='fm' action="/snp.php" method="post" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
<div class='snpcontent'>
<h1 style='color: #6e727a; font-weight: 100'> Sign Up Here </h1>
<label style='font-weight: 900'>Username</label>
<input type='text' placeholder='Enter Username' name='sname' required>
<label style='font-weight: 900'>Password</label>
<input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' name='pw' id="pw" required>
<button onmousedown="document.getElementById('pw').type = 'text' " onmouseup="document.getElementById('pw').type = 'password'" type='button' class="show">Show Password </button>
<label style='font-weight: 900'>Confirm PW</label>
<input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' name='cpw' id="cpw" required>
<button onmousedown="document.getElementById('cpw').type = 'text' " onmouseup="document.getElementById('cpw').type = 'password'" type='button' class="show">Show Password </button>
<label style='font-weight: 900'> Email </label>
<input type='text' placeholder='Enter Email' name='em' required><br>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male' required> Male<br>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female' required> Female<br>
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='other' required> Other<br>
<button type='submit' style='background-color: #19ad11; border-color: #19ad11; color: white; font-family: Georgia, verdana; width: 50%; height: 50px; font-size: 20px'> Sign Up </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it not green?

Comment: I think you are redirecting the page after successfully executing your query right?

Comment: Are you submitting the form normally or using AJAX?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description.

Comment: I am using AJAX to stay on the same page after submitting the form

Comment: I am using AJAX to stay on the same page after submitting the form, ad the AJAX works fine

Comment: Why are you hashing the email? Can you show how you are using the return in your JS? I also would swap your empty `if` with `if($pw !== $cpw) { die("Passwords do not match");}`

Comment: To be honest, now that I think about it, I have no idea why I'm hashing the email....

Comment: try checking if you are getting response or not  like this-> `console.log(response);`

Comment: Aha! apparently it says that two buttons have the same id...

Comment: Hmm, changing id's still didn't work, but thanks!

Comment: when i did the console.log, it spit out the text that i was trying to echo in the console! but how does that help me, and why does it do that?

Comment: i suggest you to post your full code .

Comment: sorry i have to go ill post my code tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I just solved my problem.
With my AJAX there's a line of code that says

```
$('#success').html(response);
```

It turns out in my

```
<h3> </h3>
```

The id was 'succes' not 'success' and that was causing the error.
Thanks for all your help!